# Is there a way to automatically pass a password to sudo without having to type it in?

Tags: macos, unix, passwords, sudo, sudoers

I have a script like this:

```
echo [password]| sudo -S

rm /Library/Application\ Support/GarageBand
ln -s /Volumes/WD\ Passport/Projects/Other\ Files/GarageBand /Library/Application\ Support/GarageBand
```

The

```
sudo -S
```

never gets my input. Is there a way to fill the sudo password without having to type it in manually from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s say your password was in the file called `password`

Pipe it into `sudo -S`

Example:

`echo password | sudo -S rm /path/to/item`

Comment: It doesn't work. The password doesn't put itself in. It ignores the pipe for some reason

Comment: @DiscepolidiGiais Are you sure that you're putting the `rm ...` on the same line as the `sudo` as shown in this answer? In your question, they're on different lines, which wouldn't work. `sudo` applies only to its parameters, not the rest of the script.

Comment: Actually I wasn't, thanks very much now it works. I'm new to coding, especially with Unix/Unix-like systems